# How to use TypeitJs with Svelte?

Tags: svelte

```
 <script>
  import TypeIt from "typeit";
  export let name;

  new TypeIt('#simpleUsage', {
  strings: 'This is a simple string.',
  speed: 50,
  waitUntilVisible: true
}).go();

</script>

<style>
  h1 {
    color: purple;
  }
</style>

<h1>
  Hello
  <span id="name"></span>
</h1>
<p id="simpleUsage"></p>
```

I imported the typeit npm module successfully, no errors logged into console but still it doesn't work.

I tried both webpack and rollup just be sure.

I know I am being very specific but can anyone help me out here. I'm new to svelte and without any errors logged into console it's hard to find the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in `<script>` runs before your markup is rendered (otherwise Svelte wouldn't know *what* to render, if you have any logic in your markup). Because of that, you can't reference DOM nodes until afterwards. The `onMount` function exists for this reason: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount

It's better to use a reference to a DOM node rather than an `id` attribute (which isn't guaranteed to be unique — if you had two instances of this component, you'd have duplicate IDs). See https://svelte.dev/tutorial/bind-this.